# AsyncTask is very Slow

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, android-asynctask

I have a very simple application, the main threat starts 2 AsyncTasks. The 2 AsyncTasks are almost the same, this is the code of one of my AsyncTasks:

```
private class waitPlayer extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       CreateLog.addToLog(e.toString);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Update your layout here
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            setCanPlay(true, lastPlayerPlayed);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

             //progress_p1.setProgress((int) progress[0]);
             //progress_p2.setProgress((int) progress[0]);

        }
    }
```

The only thing the AsyncTask does is waiting 200ms and after it's done it calls an method. The method will call the AsyncTask again. The other AsyncTask is almost the same, it only waits 3000ms and calls another method.

The problem is that after I added the second AsyncTask my Application got very slow. It freezes a few seconds when the AsyncTasks are running. My Logcat says is full of Garbage Collector notifications.

My phone is not freezing, only the Application. I have about 200mb of free RAM.

```
01-06 19:26:00.695: W/ActivityThread(25739): Application com.obattech.twoplayergame is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
01-06 19:26:00.705: I/System.out(25739): Sending WAIT chunk
01-06 19:26:00.710: I/dalvikvm(25739): Debugger is active
01-06 19:26:00.905: I/System.out(25739): Debugger has connected
01-06 19:26:00.905: I/System.out(25739): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 19:26:01.105: I/System.out(25739): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 19:26:01.305: I/System.out(25739): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 19:26:01.505: I/System.out(25739): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 19:26:01.705: I/System.out(25739): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 19:26:01.910: I/System.out(25739): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 19:26:02.110: I/System.out(25739): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 19:26:02.310: I/System.out(25739): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 19:26:02.510: I/System.out(25739): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 19:26:02.710: I/System.out(25739): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-06 19:26:02.910: I/System.out(25739): debugger has settled (1351)
01-06 19:26:03.095: D/libEGL(25739): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
01-06 19:26:03.095: D/libEGL(25739): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
01-06 19:26:03.100: D/libEGL(25739): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
01-06 19:26:03.100: D/(25739): Device driver API match
01-06 19:26:03.100: D/(25739): Device driver API version: 10
01-06 19:26:03.100: D/(25739): User space API version: 10 
01-06 19:26:03.100: D/(25739): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
01-06 19:26:03.135: D/OpenGLRenderer(25739): Enabling debug mode 0
01-06 19:26:05.680: D/AbsListView(25739): Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-06 19:26:09.415: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 92K, 5% free 12473K/13127K, paused 22ms+7ms, total 67ms
01-06 19:26:09.425: D/AbsListView(25739): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
01-06 19:26:09.425: I/MotionRecognitionManager(25739):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, listener=android.widget.AbsListView$4@42bfb580
01-06 19:26:12.515: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 120K, 6% free 12813K/13575K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 21ms
01-06 19:26:12.515: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
01-06 19:26:13.665: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 183K, 7% free 13024K/13895K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
01-06 19:26:15.205: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 535K, 9% free 12937K/14151K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 19ms
01-06 19:26:15.205: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 16ms
01-06 19:26:17.095: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 536K, 9% free 12904K/14151K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 25ms
01-06 19:26:17.095: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 7ms
01-06 19:26:17.160: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 445K, 9% free 12893K/14151K, paused 12ms+12ms, total 35ms
01-06 19:26:19.765: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 196K, 7% free 13201K/14151K, paused 5ms+5ms, total 36ms
01-06 19:26:19.765: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
01-06 19:26:23.260: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 524K, 9% free 13025K/14279K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
01-06 19:26:26.350: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 536K, 10% free 12992K/14279K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 22ms
01-06 19:26:26.350: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 5ms
01-06 19:26:28.290: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 548K, 10% free 12948K/14279K, paused 6ms+2ms, total 26ms
01-06 19:26:28.290: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
01-06 19:26:29.445: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 548K, 10% free 12904K/14279K, paused 7ms+2ms, total 30ms
01-06 19:26:29.445: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 7ms
01-06 19:26:29.510: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 137K, 8% free 13201K/14279K, paused 3ms+13ms, total 36ms
01-06 19:26:32.065: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 480K, 9% free 13068K/14279K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
01-06 19:26:36.005: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 536K, 9% free 13036K/14279K, paused 14ms+4ms, total 49ms
01-06 19:26:36.005: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 12ms
01-06 19:26:38.665: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 547K, 10% free 12992K/14279K, paused 15ms+4ms, total 48ms
01-06 19:26:38.665: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
01-06 19:26:40.605: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 548K, 10% free 12948K/14279K, paused 13ms+2ms, total 32ms
01-06 19:26:40.605: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
01-06 19:26:43.160: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 548K, 10% free 12904K/14279K, paused 13ms+2ms, total 34ms
01-06 19:26:43.160: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 4ms
01-06 19:26:43.225: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 533K, 11% free 12805K/14279K, paused 2ms+13ms, total 32ms
01-06 19:26:46.360: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 108K, 8% free 13201K/14279K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 22ms
01-06 19:26:46.360: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
01-06 19:26:47.980: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 524K, 9% free 13080K/14279K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 34ms
01-06 19:26:47.980: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 12ms
01-06 19:26:50.405: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 547K, 9% free 13036K/14279K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 21ms
01-06 19:26:50.405: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
01-06 19:26:53.925: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 548K, 10% free 12992K/14279K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 38ms
01-06 19:26:53.925: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
01-06 19:26:55.260: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 548K, 10% free 12948K/14279K, paused 8ms+2ms, total 36ms
01-06 19:26:55.260: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 10ms
01-06 19:26:57.080: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 548K, 10% free 12904K/14279K, paused 22ms+2ms, total 46ms
01-06 19:26:57.080: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 10ms
01-06 19:26:57.135: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 489K, 11% free 12849K/14279K, paused 2ms+12ms, total 29ms
01-06 19:26:58.420: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 152K, 8% free 13201K/14279K, paused 13ms+2ms, total 33ms
01-06 19:26:58.420: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
01-06 19:26:59.565: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 524K, 9% free 13025K/14279K, paused 18ms, total 19ms
01-06 19:27:02.100: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 536K, 10% free 12992K/14279K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 22ms
01-06 19:27:02.100: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
01-06 19:27:03.685: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 547K, 10% free 12948K/14279K, paused 7ms+3ms, total 29ms
01-06 19:27:03.685: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
01-06 19:27:06.535: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 548K, 10% free 12904K/14279K, paused 18ms+3ms, total 52ms
01-06 19:27:06.535: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms
01-06 19:27:06.580: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 489K, 11% free 12849K/14279K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 18ms
01-06 19:27:08.065: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 152K, 8% free 13201K/14279K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 41ms
01-06 19:27:08.065: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 19ms
01-06 19:27:11.150: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 526K, 9% free 13025K/14279K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
01-06 19:27:12.600: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 545K, 10% free 12982K/14279K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 52ms
01-06 19:27:12.600: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 26ms
01-06 19:27:15.065: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 550K, 10% free 12938K/14279K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 37ms
01-06 19:27:15.065: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
01-06 19:27:15.125: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 521K, 11% free 12805K/14279K, paused 3ms+12ms, total 32ms
01-06 19:27:19.575: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 110K, 8% free 13201K/14279K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 41ms
01-06 19:27:19.575: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 4ms
01-06 19:27:29.260: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 534K, 9% free 13028K/14279K, paused 15ms, total 19ms
01-06 19:27:50.315: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 546K, 10% free 12957K/14279K, paused 13ms+2ms, total 39ms
01-06 19:27:50.315: D/dalvikvm(25739): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms
01-06 19:27:55.140: D/dalvikvm(25739): GC_CONCURRENT freed 537K, 11% free 12803K/14279K, paused 17ms+3ms, total 36ms
01-06 19:28:05.150: W/jdwp(25739): Debugger is telling the VM to exit with code=1
01-06 19:28:05.150: I/dalvikvm(25739): GC lifetime allocation: 42530 bytes
01-06 19:28:05.510: D/libEGL(27466): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
01-06 19:28:05.520: D/libEGL(27466): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
01-06 19:28:05.520: D/libEGL(27466): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
01-06 19:28:05.525: D/(27466): Device driver API match
01-06 19:28:05.525: D/(27466): Device driver API version: 10
01-06 19:28:05.525: D/(27466): User space API version: 10 
01-06 19:28:05.525: D/(27466): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
01-06 19:28:05.550: D/OpenGLRenderer(27466): Enabling debug mode 0
01-06 19:28:19.100: D/libEGL(27760): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
01-06 19:28:19.105: D/libEGL(27760): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
01-06 19:28:19.110: D/libEGL(27760): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
01-06 19:28:19.110: D/(27760): Device driver API match
01-06 19:28:19.110: D/(27760): Device driver API version: 10
01-06 19:28:19.110: D/(27760): User space API version: 10 
01-06 19:28:19.110: D/(27760): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
01-06 19:28:19.165: D/OpenGLRenderer(27760): Enabling debug mode 0
01-06 19:28:48.755: D/AbsListView(27760): Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-06 19:28:50.325: D/dalvikvm(27760): GC_CONCURRENT freed 107K, 6% free 12461K/13191K, paused 3ms+13ms, total 31ms
01-06 19:28:50.330: D/AbsListView(27760): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
01-06 19:28:50.330: I/MotionRecognitionManager(27760):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, listener=android.widget.AbsListView$4@42bff9d8
01-06 19:28:55.810: D/dalvikvm(27760): GC_CONCURRENT freed 127K, 6% free 12813K/13575K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 22ms
01-06 19:28:55.810: D/dalvikvm(27760): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 16ms
01-06 19:28:56.915: D/dalvikvm(27760): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 181K, 7% free 13024K/13895K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
01-06 19:28:58.235: D/dalvikvm(27760): GC_CONCURRENT freed 537K, 9% free 12936K/14151K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 14ms
01-06 19:28:58.235: D/dalvikvm(27760): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 10ms
01-06 19:28:59.130: D/dalvikvm(27760): GC_CONCURRENT freed 527K, 10% free 12793K/14151K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 13ms
01-06 19:29:00.920: D/dalvikvm(27760): GC_CONCURRENT freed 104K, 7% free 13200K/14151K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 31ms
01-06 19:29:00.920: D/dalvikvm(27760): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
01-06 19:29:06.065: D/dalvikvm(27760): GC_CONCURRENT freed 536K, 9% free 13068K/14279K, paused 5ms+4ms, total 36ms
01-06 19:29:06.065: D/dalvikvm(27760): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 30ms
01-06 19:29:16.625: D/dalvikvm(27760): GC_CONCURRENT freed 547K, 9% free 13027K/14279K, paused 14ms+4ms, total 50ms
01-06 19:29:16.625: D/dalvikvm(27760): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 16ms
01-06 19:29:36.525: D/dalvikvm(27760): GC_CONCURRENT freed 540K, 10% free 12988K/14279K, paused 15ms+4ms, total 56ms
01-06 19:29:36.525: D/dalvikvm(27760): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms
01-06 19:30:06.085: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27760): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-06 19:30:13.920: D/dalvikvm(27760): GC_CONCURRENT freed 549K, 10% free 12926K/14279K, paused 20ms+8ms, total 100ms
01-06 19:30:13.920: D/dalvikvm(27760): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 50ms
01-06 19:30:13.995: D/dalvikvm(27760): GC_CONCURRENT freed 137K, 8% free 13223K/14279K, paused 13ms+3ms, total 44ms
```

Comment: Why not use a handler with postdelayed?

Comment: I never worked with a handler so I used an AsyncTask

Comment: How are you calling/starting both of your AsyncTasks? What is `setCanPlay()`? You say the second task is different from the one posted. What is the second one doing?

Comment: I recommend a Handler, too, like Raghav suggested. Also don't start with the debugger, as the debugger will significantly reduce the performance of your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wish to do something in the near future , you can use a [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) or a [timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) .

example :

this will run the runnable in about 2 seconds :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {...} , 2000);
```

asyncTask are used only for small tasks , which you don't care about the order for when they are finished and don't care how many threads are handling them .

as an example , they can be used to download small images from the internet , and be cancelled in case they are used in a listview that is being scrolled too fast .

in any case , we will need to see some more code of yours : what is "setCanPlay" ? and where is the call to the other asyncTask ?

Answer (score 7):

There is a monumental stupidity in AsyncTask. Quoting from the dev docs:

"When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

"If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR."

This means that sleeping in  AsyncTask::doInBackground will prevent all other AsyncTasks from running, until the sleep completes. You could well be preventing other background activity (perhaps system library activity) from completing.

Comment: This is *NOT* monumental stupidity.  If you want tasks to run in parallel, just use executeOnExecutor (as you say).  For the most part, though, people expect that if AT1.execute() is called before AT2.execute(), then AT1 will run before AT2.  As they found out, between DONUT and HONEYCOMB, on a raw ThreadPoolExecutor, they don't necessarily do that.

Comment: If you came to the party on Donut or later, and wrote your stuff correctly, it was a bit of a shock to find it broken on Honeycomb. I suppose, the same is true if you came to android on an earlier version, and found your stuff broken by Donut. Do two offsetting stupidites make an un-stupidity? Not sure. It still seems a bit strange to me that an Android developer should take it upon themself to unilaterally decide that everyone who was using the API was doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've Found That the Problem is That  => 
the AsyncTask class use a serial channel to compile your app on the new versions of the android like a jellybean version =>   4.2

unlike old version like Eclair version => 2.0 
it uses a parallel channel to compile the AsyncTask So if you try your app on old version 
like I've done you will see the Different 
[You See the Different Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4YFu.png)

and if u wanna to solve this problem  this  will help you :-

invoke [executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...))

with[THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)"